# JPA OneToOne not working

Tags: jpa

I followed by tutorial : http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-one-mapping-with-foreign-key-annotations-example

I have following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DomainConstant.TABLE_USER)
public class User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_USER_ID)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long userId;

    private UserActivationCode userActivationCode;

    ///////////////////// CONSTRUCTOR....
    /// STANDARD GET AND SET....


    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name =  DomainConstant.DOMAIN_ACTIVATION_LINK_ID)
    public UserActivationCode getUserActivationCode() {
        return userActivationCode;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = DomainConstant.TABLE_USER_ACTIVATON_LINK)
public class UserActivationCode {

    @Id
    @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_ACTIVATION_LINK_ID)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long userActivationCodeId;

    @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_ACTIVATION_DATE)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;

    @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_ACTIVATION_CODE)
    private String code;

    ///////////////////// CONSTRUCTOR....
    /// STANDARD GET AND SET....

}
```

When I save the `User` object it does not make record in `UserActivationCode`, why?

Like this:

```
User newUser = new User();
newUser.setUserActivationCode(new UserActivationCode("this is example"));
userDao.save(newUser);
```

I have record only in user table.

Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are mixing access types. In the User entity you have specified @Id on a field (private Long userId) whereas you have defined the join mapping on a property (the getter to UserActivationCode). If you specify the join mapping on the field, it should work as is.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = DomainConstant.TABLE_USER)
public class User{

    @Id
    @Column(name = DomainConstant.DOMAIN_USER_ID)
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long userId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name =  DomainConstant.DOMAIN_ACTIVATION_LINK_ID)
    private UserActivationCode userActivationCode;

    ///////////////////// CONSTRUCTOR....
    /// STANDARD GET AND SET....


    public UserActivationCode getUserActivationCode() {
        return userActivationCode;
    }
}
```

For more information on access and access types, see [Access, Java EE 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Access.html)